# Why/how does Microwave pulse cause electron spin to rotate in the Bloch sphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-optics, quantum-computer

I recently started studying pulse techniques for electrons in the context of quantum computing/sensing/optics/etc.

For spins in solid state (like color centers in diamond or SiC, or metal centers in molecular qubits), microwave pulses at resonant frequency can be used to rotate the spin around the Bloch sphere. As stated in the review article I'm reading "pulse phase determines the rotation axis, while the pulse power and duration set the angle."

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9780470034590.emrstm1521

My first question is *why/how* does Microwave pulse cause electron spin to rotate in the Bloch sphere? Second question is why does pulse phase determine the rotation axis / pulse power and duration set the angle (pulse power/duration seems somewhat intuitive but not really getting the pulse phase part and its relation to rotation axis)?